# How to split a line of text at delimiters

Tags: c

Here is my code. This currently opens a text file and prints a certain line depending on user input. I would like now to separate said line at appearances of a chosen delimiter (such as a comma) so I can get separate pieces of information (for example, weight, height, eye color, Name, Age, etc.).  How would I go about doing that?(Edit  im trying to use text input to determine the line printed out and nada any help?)

```
     #include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
            const char delim[2] = ",";
            char *token;
            int j =0;
            char  hh[3];
            FILE *ptr_file;
            char buf[1000];
            ptr_file =fopen("input.txt","r");
            if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;
            char *pt[] = {
                "H","He","Li","Be","B","C","N","O","F","Ne","Na"

            };
    printf("what element do you want\n");
    scanf("%s", &hh);
    for(j=0; j<= 3; j++)
    {
        if(hh == pt[j])
      {
        fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file);
                token = strtok(buf, delim);
                while( token != NULL ) 
                {
                printf( "%s\n", token );
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);
                }

                break;
      }else     
        {
            fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file);
            continue;
        }
    }    
       fclose(ptr_file);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ooh oops I'll delete that.

Comment: The `strtok()` function may do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your sentence: "Weight,Height,Eye color,Name,Age", you can tokenize the string and separate it by the comma (",") by using the

char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim) function as follows.

```
char buf[1000] = "Weight,Height,Eye color,Name,Age";
const char delim[2] = ",";
char *token;

//This retrieves the first token
token = strtok(buf, delim);

while( token != NULL ) 
{
  printf( "%s\n", token );
  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

Output:
Weight
Height
Eye color
Name
Age

Comment: So i should use my current output and run it through this?

Comment: After your first fgets() populates buf, copy from line 2 in the code I posted to the end of the while loop and place it under your fgets() call. You should see  it work they way you'd like. Next, you should optimize your block of code by placing the delimiter outside your for loop etc.

Comment: Alternately, you can just create a function with the code I shared that takes a string and a delimiter as parameters and outputs the tokens. Call that function with your populated "buf" and that should clean up the code.

Comment: its giving me an error saying str and s are not defined. Any help?

Comment: Could you take a look at it now, im trying to swap receiving a number for text and its not working?

Comment: That is because strings can't be compared using "==", you need to use strcmp() function as shown here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm